# Moving data values in a table onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I have a table and I need to move data in the cells over one cell. For instance in the following table I need the data in cells to move one, as in...cell 6 to move to cell 9 and cell 9 to move to cell 8 8 to cell 7 and so on. So only the outside cells move. Cell number 5 stays still. This all happens onclick of a button. How can this be done? Maybe an array?

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="moveStuff">Move!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I move the cell value using the button as you need.

FiddleDemo:[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QH7y5/1/)

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#moveRow").click(function () {
                var MyRows = document.getElementById("cellMove");

                var ninecell = MyRows.rows[2].cells[2].innerHTML;
                MyRows.rows[2].cells[2].innerHTML=MyRows.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML;
                MyRows.rows[2].cells[1].innerHTML = ninecell;
            });
 });
```

Comment: this is great! I'm trying to get all the cells to shift, cell one to two, two to three three to six and so on

Comment: just as this is explained here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/#comment-1272421657